# Is there an alternative to JMeter GUI and CLI to execute JMeter tests in Kubernetes without "kubectl exec"?

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, exec, kubectl

I have JMeter running as a Docker container in a Kubernetes cluster. My company's K8s team disallows calling `kubectl exec` because they don't want teams to ssh into a running container in a pod. What alternatives exist to calling bin/jmeter with params? Is there a http endpoint that can be created which can call the cli in turn? How would I implement such an API?

Comment: Could you post your `kubectl exec ...` command? Are you configuring something (changing config files) via TTY, or just simply running an application with some params and looking at output?

Comment: `kubectl -n jmeter exec jmeter-5c9bc7d769-8hvdk --container jmeter -- ls`
Host *
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "jmeter-5c9bc7d769-8hvdk" is forbidden: User "oidc:user@company.com" . Replacing ls with `/bin/bash` or anything results in the same error.

Comment: So you want only to list files in the container? You can setup `jobs` and have output saved to Persistent Volume, or alternatively store your command in ConfigMap and have the deployment recreate pod on change of the map and save output to PV as well.

Comment: No, thats just an example.. I want to run a test. Read the question

Comment: Also, saving to PV only lets the pods use that data when they restart or move. It cannot be mounted as a shared folder for me to look at test results. The workaround is to write to cloud storage from the app container as soon as the test report has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach in this case where `kubectl exec` is blocked is to create a proxy web service that would make calls to the JMeter CLI. The complete Dockerized solution with helm chart for K8s deployment is posted here - [JMeter_webservice_Kubernetes](https://github.com/jaipaddy/JMeter_webservice_Kubernetes)